# Making a website

Tags: webserver, ubuntu-14.04, hosting

I wish to put a public domain webpage on the net accessible by anyone, possibly even by a google search. I have a vultr server that I have messed around with and made a few users with sudo privileges in. What should I do from here as my next steps to reaching my goal? Step by step instructions would be godly, but a simple pointer in the right direction might be all I need with some luck.

If I have failed to provide some information let me know and I will remedy that failure as soon as I can.

If this is the wrong place to post this type of question, please let me know and direct me to where I should put this question.

I have, and work in Ubuntu 14.04.

-an aspiring idiot wishing to cure his ailment.

Comment: Your question is too broad. You want to know how to make pages available publically, how to setup web server or fix the problem you have created in your server. Please be little specific about your requirement or problem

Comment: Hi Jason. Sorry, but this question seems far too broad (and this is reinforced by your comment to Jake Charman's answer). Basically, it fails [the book test](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask): *If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.* We'll probably be happy to help you fill in gaps, but we aren't here to teach you the whole concept; other resources are much better for that. You should break this down into sub-problems and solve those one at a time until you have solved your overall problem.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't ship with a web server.  Install one first (e.g. sudo apt-get install nginx), and read the instructions (https://www.nginx.com/).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to self host a website from your home network (which I don't usually recommend) you need to open port 80 (or 443 for https) and forward it to the web server. This can be done in your router or modem configuration. Then you need to purchase a domain name (I use GoDaddy) or use a free one like .tk or .co.cc. Set the A record to your home IP. If you have a dynamic IP, it will be necessary to use a dynamic DNS service like no-IP then point a CNAME record to it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: 443 is by default for HTTPS but these ports can be changed. I agree with the rest.

Comment: I'm do not know enough to understand if this answers my question or not.

Comment: Edited @Divin3. JasonBasanese what aren't you sure about?